# Fixing CRAN note for archived R packages in `Enhances:` field

Tags: r, dependency-management, cran

I maintain an R package that enhances the functionality of a few dozen other R packages. I list those other packages in the `DESCRIPTION` file under `Enhances:`. It happens occasionally that one of them gets archived on CRAN because the authors do not respond to queries by the CRAN team. When that happens (most recently, for example, the `Zelig` package got archived), then the `R CMD check --as-cran` on my package produces a note like this:

> Suggests or Enhances not in mainstream repositories:
>     Zelig

It is very tedious to keep track manually of the status of every package my code enhances and adjust the `Enhances:` field manually each time I submit an updated version to CRAN. The CRAN policies seem to discourage orphaned packages under `Suggests:`, and I assume, perhaps wrongly, that this would apply to archived packages under `Enhances:` as well.

Therefore my question is: Is there a way to make this note go away without removing the package reference from `Enhances:`, in anticipation of the enhanced package being re-submitted to CRAN soon?